# WSO2 Identity Server Authorization Service

Tags: wso2

I am new to WSO2 Identity Server(4.6). I have a use case, where I have a rest service on ESB (WSO2 ESB 4.9). And I would like to give resource level access to various users. 
I thought of using WSO2 identity server for authorizing the user and using the token for accessing the rest service. I was going through the playground example, but that is not something I would like to do, where the Authorize service opens the Identity Server Authorization Service. It seems to be sequential, and assumes that the user/resource owner are the same.
I would like to do all that programatically, and just give the aothorization code to the user, and let him call the token service to get the token. Is this possible? 
Thank you

Comment: I get the token programtically.I am using ClientCredentialGrantType. After receiving the token I am calling a rest service. I have configured an API in ESB. And have configured a handler to validate the token with IS. I am following the [link]http://wso2.com/library/articles/2014/02/securing-your-web-service-with-oauth2-using-wso2-identity-server-1/)
I am using SOAPUI to send a Rest request. This is an empty request with header Authorization: Brearer <Access_Token>.On the ESB I am getting an exception java.lang.Exception:Error while validating OAuth2 request at SimpleOauthHandler.handleRequest

Comment: My ESB is localhost:9443 and Identity server is 9446

Answer (score 1):

You can use the https://localhost:8243/token endpoint for your use case. You can refer to below links for more information
https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/OAuth+Token+Revocation+with+WSO2+Identity+Server
https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM190/Token+API